# Is there an Italian language version of "Voldemort: Origins of the Heir"?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort-orgins-of-the-heir

*Voldemort: Origins of the Heir* is a 2018 fan film about You-Know-Who's past that was created by an Italian group. The film is dubbed into English (which is painfully obvious in the Room of Requirement scene where the audio isn't even close to matching the lip movements). I've read some people suggest that there is an Italian version that hopefully someone has "subbed", but I can't find it myself.

Was an Italian version of *Voldemort: Origins of the Heir* released? Or was it released exclusively in English, poor dubbing and all?

Comment: Where can I find a copy of this movie?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although the film was made in Italy, it would appear that the language the actors were speaking during principal filming was English. Some of the background characters and "chatter" is in Italian (and then overdubbed) but the main actors were speaking English. Dubbing errors likely come from an inability to use [ADR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dubbing_(filmmaking)) effectively and poor sound-editing rather than the words having been dubbed from Italian into English.

> Made by an Italian cast and crew, Voldemort: Origins of the Heir is
> filmed in English. **Some scenes, though, such as when the heirs gabble
> away in the Room of Requirement, look like the actors have lapsed into
> another language. Even when it is English, the vocal track is
> frequently so out of sync as to be another film altogether.**
>
> <sub><sup>[Voldemort: Origins of the Heir review: a fun-free Harry Potter fan film lifted by magical effects](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/films/0/voldemort-origins-heir-review-fun-free-harry-potter-fan-film/)</sup></sub>

There doesn't appear to be an Italian dubbed version planned for the future or at least not mentioned.